# PySpark with scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, pyspark

I have seen around that we could use scikit-learn libraries with pyspark for working on a partition on a single worker.

But what if we want to work on training dataset that is distributed and say the regression algorithm should concern with entire dataset. Since scikit learn is not integrated with RDD I assume it doesn't allow to run the algorithm on the entire dataset but only on that particular partition. Please correct me if I'm wrong..

And how good is [spark-sklearn](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn) in solving this problem

Answer (score 1):

As described in the documentation, [spark-sklearn](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn#scikit-learn-integration-package-for-apache-spark) does answer your requirements

> - train and evaluate multiple scikit-learn models in parallel. It is a distributed analog to the multicore implementation included by default
>     in scikit-learn.
> - convert Spark's Dataframes seamlessly into numpy ndarrays or sparse matrices.

so, to specifically answer your questions:

> But what if we want to work on training dataset that is distributed
>   and say the regression algorithm should concern with entire dataset.
>   Since scikit learn is not integrated with RDD I assume it doesn't allow to run  the algorithm on the entire dataset on that particular partition

In spark-sklearn, spark is used as the replacement to the [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/) library as a multithreading framework. So, going from an execution on a single machine to an excution on mutliple machines is seamlessly handled by spark for you. In other terms, as stated in the [Auto scaling scikit-learn with spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/08/auto-scaling-scikit-learn-with-apache-spark.html) article:

> no change is required in the code between the single-machine case and the cluster case.